# Tailwind using Overflow in a layout

Tags: css, tailwind-css

So I'm new to tailwind and i am creating a simple app/layout which has a **Navbar**, **Image Feed** and **Sidebar** component.

So on the left side component it has a grid of images and I want it to be a scrollable.

My issues is **overflow-y-auto** doesnt work unless I add a fixed height like **h-96** in the **Image Feed** component

Here is the tailwind code [example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/CuP2zY7Zvs) I'm working on:

**code snippet**

```
<div class="flex h-screen w-screen bg-blue-400">
  <div class="flex flex-auto flex-col">
    <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 p-4 text-white">
      <div class="flex">
        <button class="text-royal-blue h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-white text-xl"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="text-2xl">NAVBAR</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-row bg-red-200 flex-auto">
      <div class="flex flex-auto overflow-y-auto"> 
        <div class="grid w-full grid-cols-2 gap-2">
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-1/4 bg-green-300">SIDEBAR</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so try this snippet. You need to set height of the image feed container to `h-screen` and hide the overflow of the top level division.

```
<div class="flex h-screen w-screen overflow-y-hidden bg-blue-400">
  <div class="flex flex-auto flex-col">
    <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 p-4 text-white">
      <div class="flex">
        <button class="text-royal-blue h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-white text-xl"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="text-2xl">NAVBAR</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-auto flex-row bg-red-200">
      <div class="flex h-screen flex-auto overflow-y-auto">
        <div class="grid w-full grid-cols-2 gap-2">
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
          <div class="flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-800 shadow-lg"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-1/4 bg-green-300">SIDEBAR</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope still have the same issue added more items in the grid: https://play.tailwindcss.com/17dxu6oxf2?size=540x720

Comment: Here bro https://play.tailwindcss.com/CoKDebaO1t what I want to achieve is not using a fixed height on the overflow-y-auto here I used h-96 for the overflow to work.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Take a look!

Comment: Your answer have an issue  on the final scroll its cut out not showing the full item https://imgur.com/76TyzWM

Comment: A little padding-bottom (equal to height of navbar) on the image container would fix that. Another solution is to fix the position of navbar and sidebar so that the image container scrolls. But you would have to fix the height of navbar and add a padding on top equal to the navbar. I think this one is a better approach in your case. But you could go either way.